# PHP Posting data to another php file hosted in a remote server using file_get_contents

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

I have access to 3 different remote servers. They all host the same **php file**, it's named `processing.php`.

And in a different server I have 3 pages :

1. `index.html` : that contains a form with POST method that send data to `forward.php`
2. `forward.php` : that forward the form values to `processing.php` on the other servers
3. `processing.php` : Display the posted data

**The Problem :** the code in `processing.php` is not executed and the returned result is a plain text of the source code of `processing.php`!!

**forward.php :**

```
$field1 = $_POST['field1']; 
$field2 = $_POST['field2'];
rtrim($_POST['listserver'],"-");
$listServer = explode("-",$_POST['listserver']);

foreach ($listServer as $server){
    if(!empty($server)){
        $url = 'http://'.$server.'/processing.php';
        $data = array('field1' => $field1, 'field2' => $field2);
        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            echo "You can't ";
        }else{
            echo ('result : '.$result);
        }
    }
}
```

**Processing.php**

```
$field1 = $_POST['field1']; 
$field2 = $_POST['field2'];
$result = $field1+$field2;
$myFile = "files/result.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $result);   
fclose($fh);
```

But in all the servers, `result.txt` is empty!!

Comment: file_get_contents() does a GET request. If you want to POST use curl. http://php.net/manual/de/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: @MarkusZeller Not true, if you pass the correct stream context, as above

Comment: Thank you @Steve. Learned something new. Did not look at the complete code.

Comment: i suppose that you didn't forgot about `<?php` and problem is that the servers don't execute your php code, take a look at servers configurations

Comment: @SeinopSys, It's not duplicate, because my original question was about using `file_get_contents()` and i hadn't know about cURL.
But yes, that thread was very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx to @MarkusZeller suggestion, I managed to get it work using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/de/curl.examples-basic.php).

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code) was very helpful, thank you **Stack Over Flow** community !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know this is many years later, however I know why your original code was not working. You need to add an array to the headers as well. I have a similar code on one of my projects and this literally was the only difference. See example:

```
$field1 = $_POST['field1']; 
$field2 = $_POST['field2'];
rtrim($_POST['listserver'],"-");
$listServer = explode("-",$_POST['listserver']);

foreach ($listServer as $server){
    if(!empty($server)){
        $url = 'http://'.$server.'/processing.php';
        $data = array('field1' => $field1, 'field2' => $field2);
        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            echo "You can't ";
        }else{
            echo ('result : '.$result);
  

          }
        }
    }
```